# Run Load Tests during build within Visual Studio Online

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, build, load-testing, azure-devops

I've created a Web Performance and Load Test Project which, for the moment, performs a couple of simple tests on our Dynamics CRM 2013 solution using Visual Studio Online. (Tests will be expanded at a later time)

(The Load Test solution itself resides in a on-premises TFS along with all our other projects)

When I run my Load Tests on my local machine it all works like a charm.

My goal now is to run these Load Tests during the build of the solution.

It seems I have to use MSTest as Visual Studio Test Runner doesn't support Load Tests.

So I have modified my Build Template to use MSTest, with a little help of this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93c8634f-b6d6-4d8a-8c8c-b6eb6c1fad06/tfs-2013-and-webtests-and-load-tests?forum=tfsbuild

This is were I run into a problems. As I don't see an option where I can direct my Load Test to use a specific VSO account, let alone the credentials for this account.

My questions are:

- Is MSTest the best solution to start Load Tests during a build in Visual Studio Online? Is there a better one?
- If so, how do I tell MSTest to use a specific VSO account?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be running load tests, or any sort of tests that require an instance of your application, on a build server.

You should have an environment that you deploy your bits to and then run there. Microsoft have a tool specifically for this purpos called Release Manager.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

Release Manager Online is available with your account and you can easily call out to the load test or other capabilities...

Comment: The application we want to test is **not** running on our buildserver.

It is running on a dedicated Azure VM machine.

We want the load test to run using Visual Studio Online, because we want to limit the amount of maintenance on our Test Rig.

Basically we want it to work just like running the Load Test on a local machine. Start the test, upload solution to VSO, test starts, wait till the test is done and download the report.

Any hints or tips are welcome :)

Comment: Same answer: Use RM and Powershell in agentless mode.