# How do I run Visual Studio Load Tests in my build server?

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, load-testing, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up a build server script to run VS Load Tests. My preferred build server is Team City, but I would accept VSO's build server as well.

Thanks!

Comment: See answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673115/run-load-tests-during-build-within-visual-studio-online

Answer (score 1):

You should not use build server to run load test. 
Visual Studio Online provides cloud-based load test, you can use it for your testing.

Instruction about VSO Load Test: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/test/load-test-your-app-vs

Comment: But IS there a way to do it outside of visual studio online and with a normal TFS build definition?  I am in a similar situation where after we complete a build we need to kick off a load test.

Comment: Don't use build server to run load test does not mean that the build process cannot trigger load test. You can always setup your build definition to trigger a load test after the build is finished for both VSO and TFS. But you need to setup a test agent to deploy your build and run the load test or use cloud-based load test. Refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/29/testing-in-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-workflows.aspx and https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-vs.aspx#loadtest for details.